# Fancybox - not showing - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a small problem with Fancybox.

So, I have a dashboard class, with which I call open method which then opens dashboard in Fancybox. After that, when I click on another link, it should open another "feedback" fancybox and close the one that was opened before. This all works, no problem here.

```
        dashboard = new WebyDashboard();
        dashboard.open(true);

        // After closing feedback, return to dashboard
        Feedback.onClose(function () {
            dashboard.open(true);
        });
```

The problem is when I want to open first fancybox dialog when the 2nd one is closed. I define this with my onClose method as shown above.

And when I close 2nd dialog, I get error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'width' of null
```

Also, when I close 2nd dialog, the first one actually shows itself for a very short time (about half second) and then it closes. Strange.

Anyone had similiar xperience ?

Comment: Where is 'width' being called?

Comment: what version of fancybox? are you using `inline` content?